# Authentication required box is jumping around... cannot enter password

Tags: release-juno, updates

I am not able to install updates because the authentication box is "shaking". It appears it is getting an incorrect password entered error and it is responding with "Authentication failed", repeated over and over, such that I cannot type a password.

Comment: Will your system install updates and accept your password via command line in Terminal, `sudo apt upgrade`?

Comment: @David, please try adding more relevant information to the question. For example, your system information, when this problem started occurring etc. This helps people understand your situation in a more proper way. Have a nice day! 

Comment: Typed, sudo apt upgrade, and system gave this: dkpg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'   that seemed to work